# Expression language. Dominant variable

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, el

In JSP page we can access to attributes using this: `${name}`. But if we in sevlet do the following:

```
req.getSession.setAttribute("name", sessionName );
getServletContext().setAttribute("name", sevletContextName)
req.setAttribute("name", reqName);
```

then which variable  JSP will access when use ?

> ${name}

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JSP EL looks in page, then request, then session, then application.

If you want to access the session explicitely, use

```
${sessionScope.name}
```

For the servlet context, use

```
${applicationScope.name}
```

(and similarly for `pageScope` and `requestScope`)

Comment: hm, thanks. But which different between pageScope and requestScope? Request scope exist until server asnwers (because 1 request may be transfered between several servlets, jsp pages etc...), page scope exist only in 1 servlet or in 1 jsp. This right?

Comment: If you define a page scope attribute in a JSP page, using <c:set> for example, or using pageContext.setAttribute(), the attribute exists only for this page. Dynamically included pages or forwarded pages don't see this attribute. Servlets don't have page scope attributes.

Comment: Why I need use pageContext.setAttribute() instead using class variable? Because is not thread-safe? Or other reason?

Comment: Because that's where the JSP EL looks for attributes.